# Is it recommended to implement the interface this way in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

For a function type declaration in an interface; is it recommended or good practice to declare the description of another functional call in the interface as the return type? Below is the basic example of what I mean.

Component call with `testFunction` as parameter:

```
<Component
 testFunction={() => {

 // Function happens here as described in interface declaration

 }} 
/>
```

Interface declaration:

```
interface Props {
  testFunction: () => "Description of what the function does";
}
```

Comment: That's not a description, it's a [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) return type.

Comment: The name of the function should describe what it does...

Comment: It means your function will return some static string literal every time, and you don't want that the TypeScript to read that way always.

Comment: This is not a matter of good practice - if you write this, then the interface is specifying that the function *must return that exact string*.

Comment: Oh ok sure thanks everyone for the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring interface like that:

```
interface Props {
  testFunction: () => "Description of what the function does";
}
```

Will only specify the return from the function that is a `string` of value: `"Description of what the function does"`.

The name of that function, in your case `testFunction` should be self-explanatory.
Example: `onClick`, `handleUpload` etc.

Comment: Oh ok sure, thanks so much for your reply!